# Close file after a kill command

Tags: c, linux, io, flush, kill-process

I have an infinite loop in my program where it will write in a file defined as stdout until I kill it. Therefore, the file will never be closed and won't contain what was wrote.

Is there a way to close the file after a kill command ?

I could use signals, like

```
signal(SIGTERM, close(filename));
```

but how would I handle all the kill signals ?

Comment: Try adding a flush after writing (`fflush(my_file);`), inside the loop.

Comment: Don't use `signal`, use `sigaction`, and set an action for *every* possible signal (from 0 to NSIG-1). Beware that some signal can't be caught as `SIGKILL`; so you may think about flushing your buffers when critical data need to be stored.

Comment: Using `signal(SIGTERM, close(filename))` doesn't work? What function is that? and calling the function when you install the signal handler is going to "*close the file*" immediately, not when the signal triggers.

Comment: @unwind Looks like fflush() only flushes the buffering added by the stdio

Comment: "*... until I kill it.*" How exactly do you "*kill*" the process?

Comment: If you kill the process, the kernel will close the file. Your problem is *probably* that you've not actually flushed the data to the file.

Comment: @unwind : I already tried but the file went empty.

Comment: @alk : just by running kill pid_of_my_program command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is tagged with "linux", so unless you buffer your writes and don't flush the buffer (e.g. when using `fwrite` you need to call `fflush` sometimes), the contents will be written to the file because it will be properly closed on exit (even if the exit is forced by a signal). You don't need `fsync` unless you're doing something that has to survive a machine crash (and then you need to know what you're doing to get crash semantics right).

Since you mentioned `close` in what you want to do in the signal handler, it doesn't seem you're buffering your writes, so you don't need to do anything. Data written with successful calls to `write` will end up in the file unless your machine crashes (or your disk/filesystems break before flushing the buffer cache, don't worry about that). In fact, the moment `write` returns in your program, the data can be considered written into the file and will be visible by other processes that read that file (an exception to this is if the machine crashes or a few filesystem edge cases, but that's a much more complex topic).

If all you do in your signal handlers is to `close` your file descriptors and `_exit` then you don't need the signal handlers.

Comment: I forgot to mention the file is supposed to replace stdout. I edited my question.

Comment: @systemasis Doesn't change anything. stdout from the point of view of the kernel is just a number just like any other file descriptor. If you're writing buffered with `fwrite`/`printf`/`fprintf` or anything in that family you'll need to call `fflush` sometimes, but this has nothing to do with closing the file descriptors.

Comment: Just added a `fflush(stdout)` at the start of the loop and it did the trick. Thanks.

Sorry, @unwind, you were right, I just didn't put the `fflush` at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can force flush the data within your loop on some predefined intervals.You can use

```
int fsync(int fd);
```

or

```
int fdatasync(int fd);
```

fsync will flush the file from kernel buffer to the disk. fdatasync will also do except for the meta data.

Comment: This does not gurantee all data will have been flushed when the kill is performed.

Comment: `fsync`/`fdatasync` are not relevant here. `fsync` is relevant to use if you want machine crash safety but it has nothing to do with data being written by a process to a file.